# Unable to pass an argument to a python script invoked by a Tkinter Function

Tags: tkinter, subprocess

I am not able to invoke another python script in a function defined for a button created in Tkinter.

Here the code:

```
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *

def select (hf):
   subprocess.Popen("<MyScript.py> hf")

root = Tk()

var_hf = StringVar(root)
var_hf.set('Default')

option_hf = OptionMenu(root, var_hf, *["A", "B", "C"])
option_hf.pack()

button = Button (root, text = "Select", command= lambda: select(var_hf.get())
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I press the Button "Select", I get an error stating that "hf" is not recognized as a valid variable (the "hf" is called as an argument of MyScript.py).

Do you know why the function associated to the Button is not able to assign to "hf" the value taken by `var_hf.get()`?

Thank you in advance,

G.

Answer (score 0):

You are literally passing the string "hf" to `<MyScript.py>`. I'm guessing that's not what you intend to do. A simple solution is to do this:

```
subprocess.Popen("<MyScript.py> %s" % hf)
```